# Multiple click in listview android

Tags: java, android, listview

I am doing an app which shows a database users. I want add differents actions depends on zone of click in each element.

This is my actually code for this list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:layout_marginRight="20px"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:src="@drawable/icondatabase" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.91"
        android:text="Not users"
        android:textSize="70px" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageAction"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this the class which creates list:

```
public class UsersArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;
    private final List<Bitmap> listImages;
    private final String process;

    public UsersArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values,
            List<Bitmap> listImages, String process) {
        super(context, R.layout.users, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.listImages = listImages;
        this.process = process;
    }

    public UsersArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.users, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
        this.listImages = null;
        this.process = "";

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.users, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageAction);
        textView.setText(values[position]);
        if (listImages == null) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.iconenroll);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(listImages.get(position));

            if (process.compareTo("users") == 0) {

                imageView2.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);
            }

            if (process.compareTo("verify") == 0) {
                imageView2.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
            }
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

How can i do to if user clicks in imageaction do some action and if clicks in textview do other one?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can set onclicklisteners for both textview and imageview . but you have to use ViewHolders.

```
static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView imageone;
    ImageView imagetwo;
    TextView tvone;
}

 in the adapter getview

 final ViewHolder holder;
 if(convertView == null){
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view_new, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        ........
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }



holder.imageone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // do ur work 
              }
         }

      holder.tvone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // do ur work 
              }
         }
```

Comment: Why can't the OP set without using viewholders?

Comment: smooth Scrolling .

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: assuming convertView != null, if it is then you must inflate the view that is held by viewholder and set the viewholder as the tag

Comment: if you are considering performance, you should be suggesting [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html#recyclerview). And you have told the OP, that **he has to**, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

By default **textView** is not clickable, you have to set `android:clickable="true"` in your textView.

```
    textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO 
        }
    });

    imageView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView searchpageNameTextView;
    public ImageView ivStar;
  }
```

Inside getView method:

```
    View rowView = convertView;
    // reuse views
    if (rowView == null) {
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.demo, null);
      // configure view holder
      ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      viewHolder.searchpageNameTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
      viewHolder.ivStar = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivgstar);
      rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

  final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
  holder.searchpageNameTextView.setText(text you want to set);  
  holder.image.setImageBitmap(your bitmap);

  holder.searchpageNameTextView.setOnClickListener(do your stuffs);
  holder.image.setOnClickListener(do your stuffs);

  return rowView;
```

Above code is working fine. I implemented it in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can just setOnClickListeners for the respective elements in getView() of your custom BaseAdapter:

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_result_item, null);
        }
        final int fPos=position;
        ImageView image1=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img1);
        TextView tv1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        image1.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              Log.i("CustomAdapter", "List item "+ fPos +" had it's image clicked");
           }
        });   
        tv1.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
              Log.i("CustomAdapter", "List item "+ fPos +" had it's text view clicked");
           }
        }); 
        return convertView;
    }
```

Sadly setting `onClick` methods of these views make the List Row itself un-clickable since they take all focus. If youw ant your whole row to be clickable and have a seperate action for that with an `onItemClickListener` of your `ListView`, you will have to add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` tag to the parent layout of the imageview/textview and set

```
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

for the `ImageView` and `TextView` in xml.